# os.path.isdir returns false when folder exists?

Tags: python, os.path

I have the following code which checks if the directory exists

```
def download(id, name, bar):
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    dir = os.path.join(cwd,bar)
    partial = os.path.join(cwd, id + ".partial")
    print os.path.isdir(dir)
    if(os.path.isdir(dir)):
        print "dir exists"
        dir_match_file(dir, bar)
    else:
        print dir
```

For a directory that actually exists, it returns "False". Here is the output:

```
False
/scratch/rists/djiao/Pancancer/RNA-seq/CESC/TCGA-BI-A0VS-01A-11R-A10U-07
```

When I go to python interactive session and type in os.path.isdir("/scratch/rists/djiao/Pancancer/RNA-seq/CESC/TCGA-BI-A0VS-01A-11R-A10U-07"), it returns "true".

Why does it say false when the folder exists?

Comment: Are you running the code as the same user in both instances?

Comment: Change `print dir` to `print(repr(dir))`. Let's see if there is some "invisible" character there such as a CR/LF at the end.

Comment: @unutbu ah, there is a '\n' at the end. I read in bar from a file with readlines. Guess I have to rstrip it. What exactly does repr do on a string?

Comment: `repr(obj)` returns a `str` which is intended to be an *unambiguous* representation of the object. It's useful to inspect `basestrings` (`str`s or `unicode`) using `repr` since it will tell you exactly what bytes or code points the `basestring` is composed of.

Comment: You should be aware that `dir` is a built-in function. Better to pick a different variable name

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `dir` in `download` had whitespace at the end while the `dir` defined in the interactive session did not. The difference was discovered by printing `repr(dir)`.

```
In [3]: os.path.isdir('/tmp')
Out[3]: True

In [4]: os.path.isdir('/tmp\n')
Out[4]: False
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when referencing a directory using `"~"` to represent the home directory on Ubuntu. Usually, the pathing works when keeping it as `"~"`, but sometimes it doesn't. I'm not sure why it doesn't always work.

In this case, the solution is wrap the path in `os.path.expanduser` to normalize `"~"` into an absolute path to the home directory.

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: os.path.isdir("~/Datasets")
Out[2]: True

In [2]: os.path.isdir("~/Datasets/cifar10")
Out[2]: False

In [2]: os.path.isdir(os.path.expanduser("~/Datasets/cifar10"))
Out[2]: True
```